# Inserting individual array elements into sql table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Apologies in advance for this simple question however I have been trying and searching this through this forum without success.

In a nutshell I have created an array and what I require is to insert each

individual array element into database.

Here is the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $var0=$_POST['actions'];  

    $count1=count($var0);

    for($count=0;$count<=$count1;$count++)
    {
       $query1="INSERT INTO ad_tb(adDes)values('$var0[$count]')";
    }
}
```

The array as a whole is for sure created successfully as I displayed its contents using print_r. When I echo each element such as $var0[$count] that is also displayed correctly, however when I insert it in my sql insert statement nothing appears in database.

P.S. The end result desired is not every element in a single database row as many examples demonstrate this using implode. I require each and every element as a separate row in the db. Can this be achieved? As always thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Can you show where you insert the data, the SQL is not executed here (or connections made etc.).

Comment: Hi Nigel, connections is done in the script earlier on I am just showing the bit when submit button is pressed so to round things up the following is used if(mysqli_query($con6,$query1))
 {
  $message3 = "record created and saved successfully in database"; //Pop-Up Box
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message3');</script>";
 }

Comment: Can someone assist please?

Comment: You check for the mysqil_query succeeding, can you put something in which if it's false - dumps out `echo "Errormessage: ". $con6->error;`  See if that gives you anything.

Comment: yes did that , undefined offset. strange ...

Comment: Hi Nigel solved partially the problem, it was with the counter, the second problem is that if I have 3 iterations, its the third one which gets posted to db. Thank you